# Call the destructor of a template class, expected class-name before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, c++17

I have an exceptional situation where I need to call the destructor of a class to clear union memory. We can not use an `std::variant` yet. The class in the union is template based and defined similar to:

```cpp
template<class TYPE>
class BaseTemplate
{
  public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    // Other useful functions.

  private:
    TYPE value;
}
```

Now we define different types with using:

```cpp
using X = BaseTemplate<int>;
// Other using definitions
```

In an earlier situation `X` was a derived classes from `BaseTemplate`.

```cpp
class X : public BaseTemplate<int>
{ 
  X() = default;
  ~X() override = default; // In this case ~BaseTemplate was virtual.

  // Nothing useful so we would like to remove this class.
};
```

In the old situation we were able to call the destructor like this:

```cpp
X variableX;
variableX.~X();
```

In the new situation when `using X = BaseTemplate<int>;` is used this results in the error: `expected class-name before ‘(’ token`. So how do I call the destructor in this case?

Reproduction code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
namespace a 
{
class Base
{
  public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<class TYPE>
class BaseTemplate : public Base
{
  public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    ~BaseTemplate() override = default;

    // Other useful functions.
    void set(const TYPE& v) 
    {
      value = v;
    }

    TYPE get() const 
    {
      return value;
    }

    void foo() final
    {
        value *= 2;
    }

  private:
    TYPE value;
};

using X = BaseTemplate<int>;
using Y = BaseTemplate<unsigned int>;
using Z = BaseTemplate<float>;

} // End of namespace a

union XYZ
{
  XYZ() {}
  ~XYZ() {}
  a::X variableX;
  a::Y variableY;
  a::Z variableZ;
};

XYZ xyz;

int main()
{
    // Inplace new operator to initialize x
    new(&xyz.variableX) a::X;

    xyz.variableX.set(1);
    xyz.variableX.foo();
    std::cout << "Result: " << xyz.variableX.get() << std::endl;

    xyz.variableX.~X();
}
```

Comment: A [mre] might be necessary, as the code shown here doesn't produce the error shown here.  Is your `X` constructor supposed to be private?

Comment: Will be working on an example including the union. I see indeed that godbold is not reproducing my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variableX`'s destructor is called `~BaseTemplate()`. However, if `X` is in scope and resolves to `BaseTemplate<int>`, it will also work as an alias for the destructor.

If `X` was not in scope:

```cpp
some::random_namespace::X variableX;

// variableX.~X();  X not in scope, will not work

variableX.some::random_namespace::X::~X();  // Works, but confusing

// variableX.~decltype(variableX)();  // Supposed to work, but GCC does not like

using T = decltype(variableX); variableX.~T();

using X = some::random_namespace::X; variableX.~X();

using some::random_namespace::X; variableX.~X();  // Now in scope
```

The real solution is to use [`std::destroy_at(std::addressof(variableX))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at)

```cpp
std::destroy_at(&variableX);  // Does not care about the name of the destructor
```

Comment: The scope as indeed the reason. As discovered when building out the reproduction example. Thank you for your solution I will implement this.